# inconsistent results in two-way repeated measure analysis using mixed models

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, nested-data

I have two factors: `interval` with two levels, and `spd_des` with three levels. Each of the subjects (grouping variable `ratID`) repeats the experiment for each level of `spd_des`. In each of these experiments, I observe the variable `cc` for the two levels of `interval` (one observation for each level). I would like to study the effect of `interval` and `spd_des` (and their possible interaction) on the dependent variable `cc`. Basically, this is a two-way repeated measure analysis. The data look like in the image below.
[image]

I would like to use mixed effect models with the package `glmmTMB`. However, to start with something simpler, I used paired t-tests for each level of `spd_des` and I corrected the p-values with Bonferroni.

```
> s1    <- t.test(x1, y1, paired = TRUE)
> s2    <- t.test(x2, y2, paired = TRUE)
> s3    <- t.test(x3, y3, paired = TRUE)

> p_all <- c(s1$p.value,s2$p.value,s3$p.value)
[1] 0.17689345 0.02041172 0.02103782

> p.adjust(p_all,method="bonferroni")
[1] 0.53068035 0.06123517 0.06311345
```

It seems that there is no difference between the two levels of `interval` for the first level `s1` of `spd_des`, and there is a tendency (albeit not significant after Bonferroni) for the levels `s2` and `s3`. This makes sense if one looks at the image above.

Unfortunately, I get a completely different picture when I use the more correct mixed-effect models, and I wonder why. Given the design described above (in which the observations obtained for the two levels of `interval` are obtained within each level of `spd_des` within each subject), I nest `spd_des` within `ratID`

```
> linM <- glmmTMB(cc ~ interval*spd_des + (1|ratID/spd_des), data=dat_trf, na.action=na.omit,  control = glmmTMBControl(optCtrl=list(iter.max=1e3,eval.max=1e3)))
```

Running Anova on this model (with 'sum' contrast and Type III sum of square), I obtain:

> Anova.glmmTMB(linM, type = 3)
>       Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

```
Response: cc
                    Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)      434.5436  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
interval          23.6361  1  1.164e-06 ***
spd_des            0.7465  2     0.6885    
interval:spd_des   3.6512  2     0.1611
```

Now it seems that there is an effect of `interval` independently on `spd_des`. This is not consistent with the previous result, and it does not convince me much by looking at the image above (I have also tried other random effect structures: using random slope on `spd_des` or just random intercept, and I get equivalent results). **Question 1: Is there anything wrong with this model?** Here is the summary:

> summary(linM)

```
Family: gaussian  ( identity )
Formula:          cc ~ interval * spd_des + (1 | ratID/spd_des)
Data: dat_trf

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    22.2     40.1     -2.1      4.2       45 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups        Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 spd_des:ratID (Intercept) 5.092e-12 2.256e-06
 ratID         (Intercept) 1.849e-02 1.360e-01
 Residual                  5.191e-02 2.278e-01
Number of obs: 54, groups:  spd_des:ratID, 27; ratID, 10

Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2): 0.0519 

Conditional model:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         1.11193    0.05334  20.846  < 2e-16 ***
interval1           0.15137    0.03114   4.862 1.16e-06 ***
spd_des1            0.03030    0.04314   0.702   0.4824    
spd_des2           -0.03407    0.04481  -0.761   0.4469    
interval1:spd_des1 -0.07871    0.04283  -1.838   0.0661 .  
interval1:spd_des2  0.01630    0.04394   0.371   0.7108
```

[UPDATE] Turns out that if I run post-hoc tests on this model, even if there is no significant interaction according to Anova (see above), I obtain that there is significant difference between the two levels of `interval` only for some of the levels of `spd_des`. These results seem to make sense based on the picture and the simple paired ttests above. **Question 2: Should I run post-hoc on the full models even if there is no significant interaction according to Anova? If so, how do I interpret the two different results?**

```
> ph_conditional <- c("interval1+interval1:spd_des1=0",
                      "interval1+interval1:spd_des2=0",
                      "interval1-interval1:spd_des1-interval1:spd_des2=0")


> linM.ph <- glht(linM, linfct = ph_conditional);
> summary(linM.ph,test = adjusted("bonferroni"))
Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: glmmTMB(formula = cc_marg ~ interval * spd_des + (1 | ratID/spd_des), 
    data = dat_trf, na.action = na.omit, control = glmmTMBControl(optCtrl = list(iter.max = 1000, 
        eval.max = 1000)), ziformula = ~0, dispformula = ~1)

Linear Hypotheses:
                                                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
interval1 + interval1:spd_des1 == 0                       0.07266    0.05095   1.426 0.461521    
interval1 + interval1:spd_des2 == 0                       0.16766    0.05370   3.122 0.005389 ** 
interval1 - interval1:spd_des1 - interval1:spd_des2 == 0  0.21379    0.05696   3.753 0.000524 ***
```

[END OF UPDATE]

Then, I tried to fit a full model where I defined random effects of `intercept*spd_des`, and I obtained something more similar to the picture above.

```
> linM2 <- glmmTMB(cc ~ interval*spd_des + (interval*spd_des|ratID), data=dat_trf, na.action=na.omit,  control = glmmTMBControl(optCtrl=list(iter.max=1e3,eval.max=1e3)))
> Anova.glmmTMB(linM2, type = 3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: cc
                    Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)      448.8546  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
interval          35.5090  1  2.539e-09 ***
spd_des            1.2995  2   0.522170    
interval:spd_des  11.3635  2   0.003408 **
```

There seems to be a significant interaction between the two factors. When I run the post-hoc tests to compare the two levels of `interval` for each level of `spd_des` (adjusted with Bonferroni):

```
> ph_conditional <- c("interval1+interval1:spd_des1=0",
                      "interval1+interval1:spd_des2=0",
                      "interval1-interval1:spd_des1-interval1:spd_des2=0")


> linM.ph <- glht(linM, linfct = ph_conditional);
> summary(linM.ph,test = adjusted("bonferroni"))
Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: glmmTMB(formula = cc ~ interval * spd_des + (interval * 
    spd_des | ratID), data = dat_trf, na.action = na.omit, control = glmmTMBControl(optCtrl = list(iter.max = 1000, 
    eval.max = 1000)), ziformula = ~0, dispformula = ~1)

Linear Hypotheses:
                                                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
interval1 + interval1:spd_des1 == 0                       0.07266    0.04704   1.545  0.36740   
interval1 + interval1:spd_des2 == 0                       0.19857    0.06155   3.226  0.00377 **
interval1 - interval1:spd_des1 - interval1:spd_des2 == 0  0.25354    0.08649   2.931  0.01012 *
```

This now tells that for the first level of `spd_des` there is no significant difference between the two levels of `interval`, but this difference becomes significant for the other two levels of `spd_des`. I had somewhat assumed that this full model was not correct and could not be fitted because I had a single observation for each `interval:spd_des` but the results seem to be more reasonable than model `linM` above. **Question 3: Is this model (`linM2`) correct? and why?**

Note that I have checked all the assumptions for both models and they are all met: constant variance of residuals, normal residuals and normal random errors. Also, I know I could use `nlme` or `lme4`, but the former has issues at estimating the denominator DF for random slope models, and the latter provides less flexibility than `glmmTMB` in defining the structure of the var-cov matrix for the random effect (in case I needed to change it). I would use to `glmmTMB`, if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using Type III tests? Type II would be more directly comparable to the t-test.

Comment: The other thing that is going is partial pooling. You have more data across all three levels of `spd_des` to detect a difference between `intervals` than you do within each level of `spd_des`. What happens if you do a paired t-test for all observations, ignoring `spd_des`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the results are inconsistent, especially when you take the full RE structure, which corresponds most closely to the paired t-tests. The bits I notice are:

1. You're using Type-III tests. Why? It's very easy to test nonsense hypotheses with Type-III tests. Check out the classic [Exegesis on Linear Models](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf) from Venables.
2. The paired t-tests each have only a piece of the data, while the mixed model has all of the data. As such, there's more data to estimate the effect of interval and more power, at least for the marginal effect of interval across all spd_des.
3. You don't need post hoc tests for the mixed model, if you're clever with your contrasts. Or if you want something that looks more like your p-values from your paired t-test, try the `emmeans` package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a way toward the answer, but I do not understand the logic behind the first model. If RatID is the random effect, and assuming each rat really has a different ID, I do not see what the sp_des:Rat additional random effect term really means. A syntax like (1|RatID) would have been expected, for random effects on intercepts only. Especially if each rat experiences the three sp_des levels...
Indeed, if you look at the results of the model, you can see two random effect terms for the intercept: RatID and spd_des:ratID; I guess the second somehow catches up all interaction effects.
In these aspects, the second, « full », model does not have this strange random effect syntax...